# What happens in the martingale CLT if I norm by the conditional variance instead?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

*TLDR: I'm a statistician (bear with me!) trying to use the martingale CLT but I only can estimate the conditional variance instead of the unconditional one. Can I do anything to get a CLT with norming by the conditional variance?*

Suppose I have two iid data streams: $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots)$ and $Y = (Y_1, Y_2, \ldots)$ independent of each other with $E X_1^2 < \infty$ and $E Y_1^2 < \infty$. I'm trying to estimate $\theta = E X_1 - E Y_1$ by sampling $X$ and $Y$ into sample means but with a wrinkle:

The entire timeline is divided up into slices, so that at the time when there are $n$ total points there are $k(n)$ slices, where in slice $i$ we have a difference-in-sample-means estimate $\hat{\theta}_i = \bar{X}_i - \bar{Y}_i$ calculated only from data within that slice. Also suppose that at time $n$, the number of points within slice $i$ (denoted $n_i$), is non-zero, known and not random for each $1 \leq i \leq k(n)$.

Assume there is dependence between the within-slice estimates $\{\hat{\theta}_i: 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ in the following way:

- For each $i$, the probability $p_i$ that each of the $n_i$ total within-slice visitors will be sampled from stream $X$ (instead of $Y$) is a function of $\hat{\theta}_{i-1}$. Assume that $p_i \in (0,1)$ so that the $\hat{\theta}_i$'s are orthogonal.

To ease notation let $E_{n,i} := \frac{n_i}{n} (\bar{X}_i - \bar{Y}_i - \theta)$ so that we can write simply $T_{n,j} = \sum_{i=1}^j E_{n,i}$ with each $E_{n,i}$ having zero mean. Fortunately because of orthogonality of the $E_{n,i}'s$ the variance of $T_{n,i}$ is just
$$ \textrm{Var}(T_{n,j}) = \sum_{i=1}^j \textrm{Var}(E_{n,i}) $$
and from here it is straightforward enough to show that $T_{n,k(n)} / \textrm{Var}(T_{n,k(n)})^{1/2}$ has a limiting normal distribution.

**My question:** Unfortunately, in practice it's way easier to compute the conditional variances $E(E_{n,i}^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n,i-1})$ than the unconditional ones $\textrm{Var}(E_{n,i})$. Is it still possible to obtain a CLT using a norming by this conditional variance instead? For example:

$$ \frac{T_{n,k(n)}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k(n)} E(E_{n,i}^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n,i-1})^{1/2}} \to N(0,1) \textrm{ in distribution as } n \to \infty$$

Is this workable at all (maybe with mild assumptions) or is it totally missing an important point about how the CLT works?

**UPDATE 1**: I am making no assumptions on the manner of dependence of $p_i$ on $\hat{\theta}_{i-1}$ aside that $p_i$ is bounded away from 0 and 1. If it turns out that this is intractable then I'd love to investigate what conditions must be imposed to make this work!

**UPDATE 2**: I realized that my initial problem about constructing a martingale really boiled down to the question of the conditional variance vs. the unconditional one. Restructured the question to make it more concrete.

Comment: How does $p_i$ depend on $\hat{\theta}_{i-1}$?

Comment: @MarcusM Can we start by making no assumptions on this dependence and see if we can get something out of that?

Comment: In my opinion, we should put more work on the statement of your problem. At this point, it is still unclear.

Comment: In first 2 papagraphs, do you want to say ? " Given 2 arrays of random variables $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ such that i) $(X_n)$ are idd, (Y_n) are idd ii) $(X_n) \perp \!\!\! \perp (Y_n)$ iii) $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are square integrable.

Comment: ... Let  $(n_i)_{i \ge 1} $ be an array of positive real numbers. Define $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^k n_i$ ; $\hat{\theta}_i= \frac{1}{n_i} \left( \sum_{m= S_{i-1}+1}^{S_i} X_m-Y_m\right)$ "  ?

Comment: @TaroNGUYEN Yes, that is precisely what is meant. I didn't think it was too ambiguous to be honest, but I'm always happy with edits for clarity.

Comment: Not really. If your target stream data has temporal structures, for example, derivative prices, precipitation, etc, there are plenty of possible complementary hypothesis we have to clarify. And as you are looking for a theoretical result, it is essential to be clear. Nevertheless, that was to be sure.

Comment: Then, to me, the 'dependence' mecanism is not truly clear. Would you mind restating in terms of $\theta,X,Y,n_i$ ?